# How to modify the view of a new OA content type?

Tags: distributions

I followed this webinar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfStOxR9p0s

In it, Mike Potter walks you through how to create a new content type in OA and then create list view for that content type. Then he creates a new section type for that content type, where he adds the newly-created list view.

Mike did a great job and I was able to follow along fine.

At about 30:20 in that webinar, he shows that the view for the newly-created content type is just unformatted data from the content fields being spit out on to the page.

He mentions that you can do some "theming" of the page to make it look better, but doesn't cover how to do that.

Can anyone offer some guidance on that? How can I go about customizing the layout for viewing a single piece of content?

Comment: as far as theming goes with an open atrium site you should follow the steps described in [the documentation here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2377741) to create yourself a sub-theme. And then start theming as you would with any other drupal site with a panels based theme ([see the D.O. guide on theming](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme) and [the panels documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/496278)).